# Better way than using multiple templates for ng-include, if templates are very similar

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-include multiple times in my project:

```
<div ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'template2.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'template3.html'"></div>
```

My templates (1,2,3...) are very similar, only the messages are different.
I am wondering, is there a better way than having so many similar templates?

My templates are as follows:

```
<div class="card collapse">
<span class="close-button pull-right" zf-popup-toggle="popup-1">X</span>
<div class="card-divider">
    <b>{{msg-1}}</b>
    <span>{{msg-2}}</span>
</div>
<div class="card-section">
    {{msg-3}}
</div>
```

Comment: Very hard to provide an accurate answer without seeing the content of your templates.

Comment: If the message is the only thing that differs Instead of having multiple templates create a list of Ids then have an API return the appropriate message based on that Id.